# Solomining if not fully synced yet?

Tags: cpu-mining, solo-mining

I have an active daemon but get the message 'status-not mining' yet the sync progress seems to be upticking.  Very slowly.  Is there a sync routine before a mining routine in Monero?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be fully synced in order to solo mine. More specifically, you mine on top of the last (consensus) block, which is only possible if you are fully synced or, in other words, in sync with the network.

If, however, you're mining on a pool, you don't have to be fully synced (nor have to run `monerod` technically). Furthermore, you'd need one of the miners listed here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index

> Very slowly

The initial sync can take quite some time. However, thereafter, catching up every few days (or every few weeks) only takes an insignificant amount of time.